# NSView mouse events after adding subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

After I add a subview to NSView, my mouse events respond to the area of NSView minus the addedSubVIew. How can I avoid that? I want it to respond on all of the superview.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also implement the hitTest: method in the container view.

```
- (NSView *) hitTest: (NSPoint) aPoint {
    return [super hitTest:aPoint] ? self : nil;
}
```

Now only the container view can receive the mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the subviews `[NSView hitTest:]` method and return the superview.

```
- (NSView *) hitTest: (NSPoint) aPoint {
    return [self superview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a better way because I have an nsimageview, nstextfield and nstextview and I don't want to subclass all of them just to override this method. Thanks again.