# Mouse event for NSTableCellView with subviews

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nsview

I have a `NSTableCellView` with a label and two image views. When I click on the label or image view mouse events are not getting called. Is there any way to make the mouse event (mouse down in my case) to be called in view despite subviews added? Below is my code to get mouse down event,

```
class TableCellView: NSTableCellView {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }
}
```

This works when I click on the view. But it is not working if I click on the label(NSTextField) or image view(NSImageView) which are subviews of the view.

Comment: Please provide code of your view which you tried, because at my it just works.

Comment: Updated my question with the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSView mouse events after adding subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619199/nsview-mouse-events-after-adding-subview)